# classpath when run a karate mock

Tags: karate

I am coding a karate mock based on the "karate-netty" documentation (https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty) and I have a doubt:

In my mock I need to read some xml and json documents located in different paths, and I don't understand which is the "default" classpath or what should be the best strategy to read these files:

- relative paths?
- absolute paths using something similar to: read('classpath:...')

It's possible to set a classpath when run the mock using the standalone JAR?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can set the classpath. see linked answer.